# Blocking a REST API response until another API is called

Tags: rest, api, grails3

I have following scenario:

There are two API calls in an application: `api1` and `api2`.

`api1` is invoked multiple times from multiple users. I want to block all the responses of `api1` calls until `api2` is invoked. `api2` will be invoked with a parameter which would suggest to "release" the response of a specific `api1` invocation. So whenever `api2` is invoked, a specific `api1` call will respond which was blocked until now (there can be multiple `api1` releases based on the parameter passed in `api2` call).

I want to implement this in grails. I'm kind of blank how to implement this. Any ideas?

Do share if you know any other language or framework which can be used to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that came to my mind is using a mutex on the api1 call and releasing it in the `api2`. You may have to take into account the timeout of the `api1`.

**EDIT**

Well, you can have a dictionary/map of mutex's where each call has a respective mutex. When a client calls `api1`, the server generates a mutex and adds it to the dictionary, also it tries to lock the mutex(which is locked by default). After that on the `api2` you only need to provide the id that you used in the dictionary to unlock the mutex.

Comment: It also occurred to me. But I didn't know the practical implementation of the exact scenario with mutex. Timeout won't be an issue because I would deliberately set it to sufficiently high value in the calling application (consumer application which is going to call the APIs).

Comment: Well you can have a dictionary/map of mutexex where each call has a respective mutex. When a client calls api1 it generates a mutex and adds it to the dictionarry, also it tries to unlock the mutex(locked by default). After that on the api2 you only need to provide the id that you used in the dictionary to unlock the mutex.

Comment: Looks good on the theoretical level. Let me implement it and see where it goes.

Comment: I implemented it and it worked. I'm accepting your answer but I would also post my own answer with sample code. You should update your answer by adding the above comment in the answer.